# How to create nested query in hql in which we can pass id as a parameter

Tags: java, hql, hibernate-mapping

I am new to hibernate and need help. I want to fetch data from table broadcaster, and the parameter should be the `broadcasterid` (which is also fetching using sub-query from table channel(table containing broadcasterid also passing `channelid` as a parameter) but not able to do this here is my code. Please help me 
TIA

`List<Broadcaster> channels = (List<Broadcaster>) hibernateTemplate.find("FROM Broadcaster as broadcaster WHERE broadcaster.broadcasterId IN(FROM Channel as channel WHERE channel.channelCode=?",channelCode);`

I am getting the following Error

```
Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateQueryException: expecting CLOSE, found 'null' near line 1, column 167 [FROM com.concretepage.entity.Broadcaster as broadcaster WHERE broadcaster.broadcasterId IN(FROM com.concretepage.entity.Channel as channel WHERE channel.channelCode=?]; nested exception is org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: expecting CLOSE, found 'null' near line 1, column 167 [FROM com.concretepage.entity.Broadcaster as broadcaster WHERE broadcaster.broadcasterId IN(FROM com.concretepage.entity.Channel as channel WHERE channel.channelCode=?]
```

Comment: You would need a `select`clause in the subquery. But what you probably actually need is a join. What is the code of these two entities? What is the assoctaion between them?

Comment: The message `HibernateQueryException: expecting CLOSE` means that the parser is missing a closing paren at the end of the query (which is 167 characters long). Please fix that problem first.

Comment: ---broadcaster entity---                                                         @Column(name = "broadcaster_id", nullable = false)
 private String broadcasterId;
 @Column(name = "broadcaster_name", nullable = false)
 private String broadcasterName;
 @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "broadcaster")
 private Set<Channel> channels;
 @OneToMany(mappedBy = "broadcaster",fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
 private Set<Bouquet> bouquet = new HashSet<Bouquet>();

Comment: -------channel entity---                                                                  
        @Column(name = "channel_code", nullable = false)
 private String channelCode;
 @Column(name = "channel_name", nullable = false)
 private String channelname;
 @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
 private ChannelType channelType;
 @Column(name = "price",scale=2)
 private double price;
 @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
 @JoinColumn(name = "broadcaster_id")
 private Broadcaster broadcaster;
 @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
 private Category category;